# Convert PDF document to PNG file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I use c# asp.net in Visual Studio
my function is this

```
protected string ConvertPdfToPng()
{
    List<string> results = new List<string>();

    // Imposta il percorso dei file PDF e PNG
    string pdfDirectory = @"C:\pdf\";
    string imageDirectory = @"C:\immagini\";

    // Elenco dei file PDF nella cartella
    string[] pdfFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(pdfDirectory, "*.pdf");

    foreach (string pdfFile in pdfFiles)
    {
        try
        {
            // Crea il nome del file PNG basato sul nome del file PDF
            string pdfFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(pdfFile);
            string pngFileName = pdfFileName + ".png";
            string pngFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(imageDirectory, pngFileName);

            // Usa ImageMagick per convertire il PDF in PNG
            using (Process process = new Process())
            {
                process.StartInfo.FileName = "magick";
                process.StartInfo.Arguments = $"convert \"{pdfFile}\" \"{pngFilePath}\"";
                process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                process.Start();
                process.WaitForExit();
            }

            string successMessage = $"Convertito {pdfFile} in {pngFilePath}";
            results.Add(successMessage);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string errorMessage = $"Errore durante la conversione di {pdfFile}: {ex.Message}";
            results.Add(errorMessage);
        }
    }

    //return Convert.ToString(results);
    //string testo = results.ToString();
    string testo = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, results);
    return (testo);
}
```

and I don't know why it gives me this error:

> Error converting C:\pdf\test.pdf: The specified file could not be found
> the location and name of the file reported in the error are correct
> I gave read and write privileges to both folders

I'm trying with ImageMagick, but if you know a better and easier to use program I can change.

I tried giving read and write privileges for everyone to both folders and running visual studio as system administrator .

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that ASP.NET runs on your _server_, so "C:\pdf\test.pdf" must be a file on your server, not on the client?

Comment: Thanks for the reply . yes, iis server, visual studio (from which I test the program) and the folders are all on the same pc . in fact in the error the name of the file "test.pdf" is found by the function

Comment: Have you tried `process.StartInfo.Arguments = $"\"{pdfFile}\" \"{pngFilePath}\"";`

Comment: using instruction process.StartInfo.Arguments = $"\"{pdfFile}\" \"{pngFilePath}\"";  
i have the same error

Comment: I solved it with the use of poppler from c#
I would like to write the solution in case it could be useful to someone else
since I'm new to the site I ask if I have to write it here in the comments or if I have to do it another way
thank you all and especially to @K J who suggested how I fixed it

Comment: You can actually post as an answer to yourself.  Don't try and post code in comments- no one can read and no formatting exists in comments

Answer (score 1):

I solved with this solution
I thank everyone and especially KJ for the pointer

```
    protected string  ConvertFirstPdfToPng(string pdfDirectory, string outputDirectory)
{
    List<string> results = new List<string>();
    try
    {
        string popplerPath = @"D:\poppler-23.08.0\Library\bin\pdftoppm.exe";

    int resolutionDpi = 300;

        // Ottieni una lista di file PDF nella directory specificata
        string[] pdfFiles = Directory.GetFiles(pdfDirectory, "*.pdf");

        if (pdfFiles.Length > 0)
        {
            // Prendi il primo file PDF trovato (puoi personalizzare questa logica)
            string pdfFilePath = pdfFiles[0];

            // Crea un nuovo processo
            Process process = new Process();

            // Specifica il file .exe da eseguire (pdftoppm.exe)
            process.StartInfo.FileName = popplerPath;

            
            // Specifica gli argomenti del comando
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = $"-r {resolutionDpi} -png \"{pdfFilePath}\" \"{outputDirectory}\\output\"";
            


            // Imposta la directory di lavoro del processo (se necessario)
            process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = outputDirectory;

            // Abilita la creazione di una finestra per il processo (potrebbe essere necessario a seconda dell'applicazione)
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;

            // Avvia il processo
            process.Start();

            // Attendi che il processo termini
            process.WaitForExit();

            // Chiudi il processo
            process.Close();

            string successMessage = "Convertito";
            results.Add(successMessage);
        }
        else
        {
            string nofile= "Nessun file PDF trovato nella directory specificata.";
            results.Add(nofile);
            
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Gestisci eventuali eccezioni qui
        string error = ("Errore durante la conversione del PDF in PNG: " + ex.Message);
        results.Add(error);
    }

string testo = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, results);
return (testo);
```

}